# Does kivy have a widget that's equivalent or comparable to wxPython's XLSGrid Widget?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

Like the title says, is there a Kivy widget that displays excel files or .ods files in a fashion that's similar too or better than wxPythons XLSGrid?

The output would look something like this https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2011/08/20/wxpython-new-widget-announced-xlsgrid/

I can think of a few ways of doing it, (i.e,) generating labels or buttons and TextInputs so that it looks like an excel sheet. But I'm hoping that there is an easier way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching around, a lot, it seems like there is no widget which is similar or even comparable to above example (or the QTableWidget). Unfortunately, this means I'll either have to design my own custom widget (which isn't an issue) or build it all inside the kv section.